# Change the order of the 'Search this site' form in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, preprocessor, theming

I need to change the layout of the Search Block in Drupal. It’s currently ordered

**Search Button > ‘Search this site’ > Search Input**

but the designs I have want it to be

**Search Input > ‘Search this site’ > Search Button**

How do I go around changing the order in Drupal? I can change the `search-block-form.tpl.php` so the submit button is at the end but the ‘Search this site’ always appears before the input and I would like it after.

I hope that makes sense. I can also do it using CSS but I’d prefer to use Drupal?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the following two theme preprocessing functions to do that. The one to use depends on if you're using the search block or just embedding the search form into your .tpl.php

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/template_preprocess_search_block_form/6
http://api.drupal.org/api/function/template_preprocess_search_theme_form/6

Comment: Thanks mcrittenden and sorry it's taken a whole weekend for me to respond. I will give it try when I'm back in work tomorrow and thanks again for the help.